# ERROR: org.apache.jasper.JasperException after deploying the project

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I couldn't understand why there is problem after deploying the project. It is working fine while running in netbeans with postgreSQL. BUT after deploying the project in tomcat server I get error like follows:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: [42] in the generated java file:
>   [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   8.0\work\Catalina\localhost\LEAVE\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java] The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type
>   HttpServletRequest

Comment: paste ur jsp, and please double check if u are making any mistake in ur jsp, this error is telling ur jsp is not error free

Comment: I solved it by replacing the version of javax-servlet and it workin now